# adding multiple same documents using addtoset command in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My schema is

```
var UserQuizSchema = mongoose.Schema({   
        uid:{type:ObjectId,required: true,index:true},
        answer:[{content:String, qid:ObjectId ,time:Date }],        
});
```

In this schema, 'uid' represents user identifier, while the 'answer' array stores the answers the student had answered. in each answer, qid relates to the question ID, and 'content' is the student's real answer, 'time' is the modified time stamp for the answer.

Here I use mongoose to upsert the new answers into the array

```
function updateAnswer(uid,question_id,answer,callback){

    var options = { new: false };   
    var quiz_id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(quiz_id);
    var qid = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(question_id);
    UserQuizModel.findOneAndUpdate({'uid':uid},{'$addToSet':{'answer':{'qid':qid, 'content':answer} } },options,function(err,ref){
        if(err) {
            console.log('update '.red,err);
            callback(err, null);
        }else{
            console.log('update '.green+ref);                 
            callback(null,ref);
        }
    })
}
```

In the common sense, by using addToSet command, the element in the answer array should be unique, but in my example, the answer array could have multiple same embedded documents only except each embedded document has one unique OjbectId _id

such as

```
 answer:
  [ { qid: 5175aecf0e5b061414000001, _id: 518a5e5895fc9ddc1e000003 },
    { qid: 5175aecf0e5b061414000001, _id: 518a5e5f95fc9ddc1e000004 } ] }
```

you see the qid of two embedded documents are the same, but _id are different.

Why there is a additional _id, I don't put it the schema design ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable the `_id` in your embedded objects by explicitly defining a schema for the elements with the `_id` option set to false:

```js
var UserQuizSchema = mongoose.Schema({   
    uid:{type:ObjectId,required: true,index:true},
    answer:[new Schema({content:String, qid:ObjectId, time:Date}, {_id:false})]
});
```

Comment: thanks, Johnny, it is true the '_id' disappeared. but another problem is using '$addToSet' command to add the same embedded document multiple times causes multiple same embedded documents in the array

Comment: @user824624 Can you update your question with a minimal example that reproduces the problem you're seeing?